# Can't get mongoose findById() working

Tags: mongoose

From the Mongo Shell

```
db.messages.find({_id:ObjectId('57b12ca68ea2e15c182044f3')})
```

Works and prints the record to the screen.

From express `http://localhost:3000/messages/57b12ca68ea2e15c182044f3`

```
app.get('/messages/:id', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Searching user with ID: ' + req.params.id);

  // message is always null, have tried without "mongoose.Types.ObjectId" but it is still null
  Message.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id), function(err, message) {
    console.log('Found record');

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(message));
  });
});
```

I get a null response every time.  I have tried without using ObjectId wrapper but I still get null values.  The mongoDB connection is fine because I have a `Message.find({}, function(err, messages) { ... }` returns all the messages successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check `err` if there is an error?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the schema for `Message` and the document you're trying to find?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have it with me right now.  Will add it tomorrow.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, you led me in the right direction, I had defined `_id: String,` in the mongoose schema.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I incorrectly defined `_id: String` in the mongoose schema file which caused this issue.  Removing the `_id` definition completely solves this.